# Plot percentage of genome covered

Tags: wgs

Given a aligned bam file (wgs/bwa-mem) what steps do i need to perform to generate a plot as seen below (from this [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0066621)):

[image]

We are trying to see how much of genome was covered using pacbio and illumina for cow.

---

You mean remove this left plot?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general steps are:

1. Install [deepTools](http://deeptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/installation.html)
2. Run [plotCoverage](http://deeptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/plotCoverage.html) on your BAM files
3. Remove the left-most plot in photoshop/gimp/imagemagick

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Yes, I mean the left plot in the example, since it looks like you want % >= the coverage value on the X axis.

Answer (score 1):

Devon gives a practical answer using the great deepTools package. These should be the theoretical, lower level steps behind the plots:

- Compute read depth at each genomic position, using for example `samtools mpileup` with appropriate flags to accept/reject reads. You get a table like:

  ```
  Pos       Depth
  chr1:1    0
  chr1:2    10
  chr1:3    11
  ...
  chrX:100  10
  ```
- For each unique value *x* in the *Depth* column count how many genomic positions have depth >= *x*. You can use Unix tools like `sort ... | uniq -c | awk ...` for this. You get a table like:

  ```
  Depth   N bases with depth >= x   % bases with depth >= x
  0       (all genomic positions)   100 %
  1       1000                      90 %
  2       995                       85 %
  .
  .
  .
  N       2                         0.1 %
  ```
- Now just plot column `Depth` (x) vs `% bases with depth >= x` (y) with R or you favourite plotting tool.

Did I get it right?

Comment: yes, not sure bust does picar collectwgsmetrics do something similar?